# Changing the size of an operator according to its argument?

Tags: math-mode, spacing, equations

I'm trying to use a Laplace transform symbol as an operator, so far it looks good, but I want it to be of the same size as the argument that it's working with, so if the argument has one row, the Laplace transform would be of the same hight as one row, and if the argument is a fraction with 2 rows, enlarge the symbol of the operator.

```
class test2(Scene):
def construct(self):
    my_template = TexTemplate()
    my_template.add_to_preamble(
        r"""
        \usepackage{mathrsfs}
        \let\RSFSmathscr\mathscr  % save the meaning of \mathscr
        \usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
        \let\RSFSOmathscr\mathscr % save the new meaning of \mathscr
        \let\mathscr\RSFSmathscr  % restore the previous meaning

        \newcommand{\Laplace}{\RSFSOmathscr{L}}
        """)
    tex = MathTex(r"\Laplace \left \{ \frac{1}{s^2 + 1} \right \}", tex_template=my_template)
```

and this is the result I'm getting

[image]

I would also like to add the arguments t and s, similar to wolfram alpha do it, here is an image of that.

[image]

in other words, the final result should look something like this:

[image]

I was thinking of maybe something like this?:

```
            \usepackage{mathrsfs}
            \let\RSFSmathscr\mathscr
            \usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
            \let\RSFSOmathscr\mathscr
            \let\mathscr\RSFSmathscr
            
            \newcommand{\Laplace}{\RSFSOmathscr{L} _t \left\{ somehow_argument_here  \right \} (s) }
```

Comment: In the first picture, you used curly braces after the Laplace symbol. In the second picture, you changed to square brackets. Sometimes you have subscript for the L symbol; sometimes you don't. Can you please clarify which version do you want?

Comment: the first picture was made by me, the socond didnt, but I want a mix of the 2 with: curly braces, subscript t in the laplace symbol, and I want the laplace symbol as the first pic, also at the end of the argument should be the (s), so I could use for example \Laplace and only indicate the argument \frac{1}{s^2 + 1}

Comment: You are probably looking for this definition then: `\newcommand{\Laplace}[2][t]{\mathop{}\!\mathscr{L}_{#1}\!\left\{#2\right\}}`. Then in the document body you say `\[ \Laplace{ \frac{1}{1+t} }(s) \]` or `\[ \Laplace{ \sin t }(s) \]`. You can even use different arguments such as `\[ \Laplace[u]{ \exp(-u) }(x) = \frac{1}{1+x} \]`

Comment: It compiles errors, maybe something with the syntaxis?

Comment: what does ```\mathop{}\!``` do?

Comment: My proposed definition of `\Laplace` takes one mandatory argument, which is the function you throw into the Laplace transform. It also accepts an optional argument, which you can use to replace the subscript. The syntax is `\Laplace[<optional arg>]{<mandatory arg>}`.

Comment: im not really sure why but it returns errors even while trying out ```tex = MathTex(r"  \Laplace{ t } ", tex_template=my_template)```

Comment: if i understood it, it should use t as a default when you dont use the optional argument, so it shouldnt be neccesary, and let work ```\Laplace{ t }```

Comment: Are you sure you are compiling on LaTeX? `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathrsfs} \newcommand{\Laplace}[2][t]{\mathop{}\!\mathscr{L}_{#1}\!\left\{#2\right\}} \begin{document} You can write \[ \Laplace{\sin t}(s) \quad\mbox{and}\quad \Laplace{\frac{1}{t+1}}(s) \] \end{document}` runs fine on my computer.

Comment: its manim, but still it acces latex via miktex, so as long as the code works in Latex there shouldnt be any problem

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by putting the ℒ and its arguments in boxes, and resizing them.  Since you want to be able to add subscripts, I made that an optional argument.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % To format the MWE for Tex.SX
\usepackage{iftex} % For \iftutex
\usepackage{settobox} % For \settoboxheight
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \resizebox

\iftutex
  \usepackage{newcomputermodern} % For example
%% By default, \mathscr duplicates \mathcal.  You wanted a symbol like
%% Boondoxo, which is available as a stylistic set in the STIX fonts.
  \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase,
    StylisticSet=1,
    range={scr, bfscr}]
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern} % For example
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}
\fi

\newlength{\LaplaceHeight}
\newbox{\LaplaceArg}
\newcommand\Laplace[2][]{%
  \savebox{\LaplaceArg}{\(#2\)}%
  \settoboxheight{\LaplaceHeight}{\LaplaceArg}%
  \mathop{\resizebox{!}{\LaplaceHeight}{$\mathscr{L}$}}\nolimits_{#1} \usebox{\LaplaceArg}%
}

\begin{document}
\[ \Laplace{\sin t}(s) \]

\[ \Laplace[t]{\left\{ \frac{1}{t+1} \right\} }(s) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Laplacian sample, on the baseline]

This version matches only the height and not the depth.  To match your illustration more closely, but drop below the baseline, you can instead resize to the argument’s total height and lower by its depth:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[paperwidth=10cm]{geometry} % To format the MWE for Tex.SX
\usepackage{iftex} % For \iftutex
\usepackage{settobox} % For \settoboxtotalheight, \settoboxdepth
\usepackage{graphicx} % For \resizebox

\iftutex
  \usepackage{newcomputermodern} % For example
%% By default, \mathscr duplicates \mathcal.  You wanted a symbol like
%% Boondoxo, which is available as a stylistic set in the STIX fonts.
  \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[
    Scale=MatchUppercase,
    StylisticSet=1,
    range={scr, bfscr}]
\else
  \usepackage{lmodern} % For example
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage[scr=boondoxo]{mathalpha}
\fi

\newlength{\LaplaceHeight}
\newlength{\LaplaceDepth}
\newbox{\LaplaceArg}
\newcommand\Laplace[2][]{%
  \savebox{\LaplaceArg}{\(#2\)}%
  \settoboxtotalheight{\LaplaceHeight}{\LaplaceArg}%
  \settoboxdepth{\LaplaceDepth}{\LaplaceArg}%
  \mathop{\raisebox{-\LaplaceDepth}{\resizebox{!}{\LaplaceHeight}{$\mathscr{L}$}}}\nolimits_{#1} \usebox{\LaplaceArg}%
}

\begin{document}
\[ \Laplace{\sin t}(s) \]

\[ \Laplace[t]{\lef
```

[image: Laplacian sample]

As several have mentioned in the comments, scaling the ℒ makes it look too heavy. You could possibly scale it only along the vertical axis, but that doesn’t look good either.

Here’s an alternative you might like better, which defines a normal-size `\laplace` and a double-sized `\Laplace`, scaling up the latter from a lighter weight of the font family.  It requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2

\usepackage{newcomputermodern} % For example
\setmathfont{KPMath-Regular}[ Scale=MatchUppercase, range={scr,bfscr}]
\setmathfontface\bigmath{KPMath-Light}[Scale=2.0]

\newcommand\laplace{\mathop{\mathscr{L}}\nolimits}
\newcommand\Laplace{\mathop{\bigmath{ℒ}}\nolimits}

\begin{document}
\[ \laplace{\sin t}(s) \]

\[ \Laplace_t {\left\{ \frac{1}{t+1} \right\} }(s) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: KPMath sample]

Comment: this does what the OP asks but I hope having seen the result they choose not to scale the L !

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is an issue, yes. They *might* instead select a text L from a lighter script font? It’s really up to them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle @Davislor That humongous `L` just looks awful…

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Maybe you like this better? Could add some negative kerning to the subscript.

Comment: @RuixiZhang Maybe you like this better?

Comment: or is it possible to make the stroke of the L thinner instead of changing the type of L?

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias The easiest way to do that is the one I posted at the bottom of my answer, but I suppose you can draw anything as a Bézier curve.

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias I would not scale the L at all sorry. At most I would use a similar scheme as for `\sum` and `\int` and have just two sizes and  use a slightly larger one in display math (whatever size expression)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does my third solution look good to you?

Comment: good enough, thanks for humouring my moans I'd better vote:-) oops I already had!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the following code may get to your goal:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\Laplace}[1]{\mathop{}\!\mathscr{L}_t\!\left\{#1\right\}\!}
\begin{document}
You can write
\[
\Laplace{\sin t}(s)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\Laplace{\frac{1}{t+1}}(s).
\]
Let's leave ``$(s)$'' out of the definition, so you can write
\[
\Laplace{\exp(-t)}(s)=\frac{1}{s+1}
\quad\text{and}\quad
\Laplace{\exp(-t)}(x)=\frac{1}{x+1}.
\]
You can even write some savvy convolution:
\[
\Laplace{(f\ast g)(t)}(s)=\Laplace{f(t)}(s)\Laplace{g(t)}(s),
\]
where $\ast$~is the convolution symbol defined as
\[
(f\ast g)(t)=\int f(x) g(t-x) \, dx.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Laplace]

The `\mathop{}\!` at the very start takes care of spacing (when you write product of Laplace transforms, it adds a tiny amount of space to separate the terms). If you don’t like it, you can remove it. The other two `\!`’s cancel the extra spaces around `\left\{...\right\}`.

Comment: well looks very close, but is it possible to enlarge the Laplace transform as the integral symbol?

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias even integrals are not normally scaled to the size of the expression. The other answer shows how to scale the L but the result is already ugly and gets progressively worse if the expression gets bigger.

Comment: im getting an error every time I try to use `\!` it says `LaTeX Warning: Command \! invalid in math mode on input line 44.` I think i need to add some `\usepackage` in order to use it, do you know which one could be?

Comment: also the whole thing about making the L bigger was to emulate the \displaystyle that the integrals have

Answer (score 0):

The `\scalerel` macro takes its first argument and scales it to the vertical footprint of the 2nd argument, working in math mode.  Adjustments needed were to exclude the `_t` from the scale calculation, and to have a minimum size of the scale-to footprint, in this case the size of a cap `X`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \let\RSFSmathscr\mathscr
  \usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
  \let\RSFSOmathscr\mathscr
  \let\mathscr\RSFSmathscr
\newcommand{\Laplace}[1]{\scalerel{\RSFSOmathscr{L}
  \smash{_t}}{\vphantom{X}#1} (s) }
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
\Laplace{\sin t}
\]
\[
\Laplace{\left\{\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right\}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**SUPPLEMENT**

The OP asks, I think, if the size of the Laplace operator can be made smaller in the second case, perhaps a fraction of the height of the argument, rather than the full height of the argument.  Here, I make it .6 times the height of the argument, with a minimum size corresponding to the size of capital `X`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
  \let\RSFSmathscr\mathscr
  \usepackage[scr]{rsfso}
  \let\RSFSOmathscr\mathscr
  \let\mathscr\RSFSmathscr
\newcommand{\Laplace}[1]{\ThisStyle{
  \sbox0{$\SavedStyle#1$}
  \ht0=.6\ht0
  \dp0=.6\dp0
  \scalerel{\RSFSOmathscr{L}
  \smash{_t}}{\vphantom{X\box0}}#1 (s)}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\begin{document}
\[
\Laplace{\sin t}
\]
\[
\Laplace{\left\{\frac{1}{t^2+1}\right\}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this one worked like a charm for me, the only things I think could be improved are to make the width of the stroke thinner so that it matches the rest of the expression, and also change a bit the spacing so that the operator isn't as far of the `{` symbol

Comment: `\smash{_t}}{\vphantom{X}#1}` this part is for making the `_t` the size of the capital X right?, if I want to make it half the size of its current height is enough to just change the capital X with normal x?

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias Not exactly.  The `\smash{_t}` removes the subscript from the scaling measurements all together.  the `\vphantom{X}` says to always consider the argument to be at least as tall as an `X`, and the `#1`, in addition to typesetting the argument, has it's height used in figuring out how big to make the script-ell.

Comment: @MiguelFernandoMaciasMacias Please see the supplement to my answer, as a response to what I think you are asking.