# Uppercase R as a big operator

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I would like to use a big mathcal R for the Ramanujan summation.
From a previous question ([Math operator resizing in autosized brackets](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53155/math-operator-resizing-in-autosized-brackets)), I got

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\xRsum#1#2{\hbox{#1$#2\mathcal R$}}
\newcommand\Rsum{\mathop{%
    \mathchoice
    {\xRsum\huge\displaystyle}%
    {\xRsum{}\displaystyle}%
    {\xRsum{}\scriptstyle}%
    {\xRsum{}\scriptscriptstyle}%
}}

\begin{document}
    $$\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k\neq-\frac1{12}\qquad\Rsum_{k=1}^{+\infty}k=-\frac1{12}$$
    $$\frac1{\Rsum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{k^2}}=\frac1{\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac1{k^2}}$$
\end{document}
```

but it does not correct produce output.

[image: output]

You can see everything is aligned very badly.

Comment: Unfortunately, closing this as a dupe doesn’t let me post this as an answer, but: upscaling this way makes the script R come out too heavy. Therefore, your `\displaystyle` variation should actually upscale a lighter-weight math font, such as `KPMath-Light, while your `\textstylr` variation should use something like KPMath-Regular. If you have to use a math font that doesn’t come in light weight (and most don’t), you can at least use `\mathbfscr` versus `\mathscr` for consistency.

Comment: For example, the solution [at the bottom of this answer,](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/581083/61644) but wrapped in `\mathop` for series-like spacing and limits.

Comment: @Davislor Thank you for your answer, my biggest issue is size/alignment but indeed it come out too heavy. I will take a look at this answer